# macOS でプロセスごとの仮想メモリサイズを知るコマンドってありますか？

Tags: macos

GNU の `top` だと以下の通り **VIRT** という項目があります。

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
```

一方、Mac の top で表示される結果は GNU 版と異なり、**VIRT** の項目が見当たりません。

```
PID    COMMAND      %CPU TIME     #TH   #WQ  #PORT MEM    PURG   CMPRS PGRP  PPID  STATE    BOOSTS            %CPU_ME %CPU_OTHRS UID  FAULTS     COW      MSGSENT    MSGRECV    SYSBSD
```

top コマンドのマニュアル (`man top`) に以下の記載があるので、これがそうなんでしょうか？

> PURG: Purgeable memory size

あと man の中に CMPRS という単語が出てこないのでこれが何なのかわかりません。

Comment: CMPRS に関して、これはプロセスに含まれる `CoMPResSed data` のサイズです。この記事 [Understanding Compressed Memory on the Mac](https://www.lifewire.com/understanding-compressed-memory-os-x-2260327) で概略が説明されています。

Comment: @KTI 以前にもお伝えしましたが、できれば句読点を正しく使ってくれた方が文章としては読みやすいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. アクティビティモニタで見る（ⓘマークを押す）※コマンドではありません。

[image: アクティビティモニタ]

2. ps コマンドを使う（vsz オプション）

```
% ps x -o rss,vsz,command

   RSS      VSZ COMMAND
  3280  4302932 /usr/sbin/distnoted agent
  6136  4358868 /System/Library/Frameworks/LocalAuthentication.framework/Suppor
  3020  4331460 /usr/sbin/cfprefsd agent
 12164  4368288 /usr/libexec/UserEventAgent (Aqua)
  9384  4364396 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudServices.framework/Helpe
 18536  4372088 /usr/libexec/knowledge-agent
  8924  4373108 /System/Library/CoreServices/talagent
 35112  4976672 /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/MacOS/Dock
 32516  5106820 /System/Library/CoreServices/ControlCenter.app/Contents/MacOS/C
 10476  4365824 /usr/libexec/lsd
...
```

参考：[How can I monitor memory usage of a process running from the terminal in OSX](https://superuser.com/q/700126/1197980)

Comment: どのプログラムも４GB以上使ってるのでMACだとそういうものなんですね…